# Metarig setup - curled fingers or straight?

Tags: rigging

Just a workflow/process question, and it may be about personal preference. I've been building my character models using Dikko's youtube videos as a guide, and left the hand models with the fingers straight. When I add the Metarig, the fingers are curled slightly. It's not a big deal to straighten them out, and they curl correctly (thanks to the previous Q/A threads here!).

When you folks build your models, do you set them up with curled fingers to match the metarig? Or straighten the fingers of the metarig to match your model? What's your preference, and your reason?

For context, I'm building models for an animatic/storyboard, so not a final render model and not for gaming/framerate optimization.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether I'm going to modify the rig to provide I/K control for the fingers. I rarely do that, because for 99% of my usage the default curling controls work fine. If I want an I/K control, though, I curl the fingers slightly just as you would any I/K joint. It helps the I/K solver know which way to bend the joint.

Otherwise, it's easier (for me, at least,) to model most bipedal characters without the bend. As you point out, the default curling controls work in that case, so I straighten the metarig to match the finger joints.

To make that easier for myself, I tend to use topologies that allow me to snap the bones to the center of the joint.

As far as I know, it comes down to whether your modeling workflow lends itself to the curve or not and there's no other reason to select one approach over the other.

Comment: "To make that easier for myself, I tend to use topologies that allow me to snap the bones to the center of the joint." - This interests me. Is there a youtube link that goes into more detail, that a newbie like me would understand? Or do you just put the 3d Cursor in the middle, and snap to that?

Comment: The trick I  use is to model the joint as a symmetric 'cage', sometimes just a cube.  Select all of the vertices that make up the cage and snap the cursor to selected. Then switch to the armature, select the tip of the bone and snap selected to cursor.  It's a bit time consuming but it gives perfect placement.